# Different results for NSS depending on where the user is logged in

Tags: linux, pam, nss

When I call `getpwuid` it returns data from where `NSS` told it. In a `PAM` enabled system, we can authenticate a user logged in from console differently with a user logged in via ssh, but with NSS it is fixed (as I understand it).

When I log in through the console, the `login` binary first authenticates through PAM and then tries to get user data via NSS. I can set custom rules for `login` and `ssh` in `/etc/pam.d/`, but for NSS it seems there is no way to do this.

How to get users' data (`getpwuid`) based on the location where the user is logged in?